# Is there a more efficient way to make this program?

Tags: python

Is there a more efficient way to make this program?

```
#This is The Collatz Sequence Program

def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        evenNumber = number // 2
        print(evenNumber)
        return evenNumber
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        oddNumber = 3 * number + 1
        print(oddNumber)
        return oddNumber


print('Please Enter a Number:')
try:
    n = int(input())
except ValueError:
    print('You must enter an integer:')
    n = int(input())


value = collatz(n)

while value != 1 :
    value = collatz(value)
```

Link: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

when you type 3 it goes like follows :

```
3
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
and it always ends with 1.
```

Comment: Please use the code option of the editor to please format your code properly.

Comment: Please explain what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: [codereview.se] - For starters, the `elif` can just be `else`, but not sure how many microoptimisations you're looking for

Comment: For the most part, this program is a pretty decent starting point. I wouldn't worry about optimizing it too much, you're using good names, the code flow is clear, I don't really see any major issues.

Comment: Thank You all I was just wondering is there another way to do it more concisely.

Comment: If you post this question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) could you 1. Change the title to describe what you code is doing 2. Add a very short description - a link to Wikipedia would probably suffice. 3. Move your title to the question body.

Comment: @MeteHunt Check the updated solution. I have tested for 19 and 27 as the solution for this both is given in above wikipedia link

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return number // 2

    elif number % 2 == 1:
        return 3 * number + 1

while True:
  try:
      n = int(input('Please Enter a Number:'))
      print(n)
      while n!= 1:
        n = collatz(n)
        print(n)
      break
  except ValueError:
      print('You must enter an integer')
```

Comment: It is not working properly there are no errors but program`s main point is to make value 1 at the last point. Loop should  end when the value == 1    this is the wikipedia link for this program`s principle = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

Comment: @MeteHunt I have tested for 19 and 27 as the solution for this both is given in above wikipedia link